# IllegalStateException: failed to find Build Tools revision 26.0.0-rc2 : Is O preview incompatible with android gradle plugin 2.1?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-8.0-oreo

When using gradle 3.3 and android gradle plugin (AGP) version 3.0 alpha through 2.2, I have no issues building with build-tools 26.0.0-rc2. But in the same project, targeting the same SDK, if I try to use AGP 2.1 I get the `IllegalStateException: failed to find Build Tools revision 26.0.0-rc2`

Im hoping to determine if this is a bug in O preview, or if this is simply incompatible. If it is the latter, I would be interested in any official statement of compatibility between AGP, android studio, and what build-tools a project is configured to use. Ive not been able to find any reference to this documented by Google.